# .htaccess rewrite cond for adobe muse

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, muse

I have an adobe muse site that office staff update. However I want to add an html file at the top level so that I have example.com/recruitment-advertising.html minding its own business and just working separate from adobe muse.

I have tried to exempt the file from muse in the .htacess file using a condition but the page keeps coming up

> Page Not Found
>
> We could not find the Web Page you requested. This is either because:
>
> There's an error in the address or link. Or you have entered the
>   address or link incorrectly.

It is probably syntax, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My .htaccess file currently looks like

```
# Begin Muse Generated redirects
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/recruitment-advertising\.html$
    RewriteRule ^muse_test_redirect.html$ muse_test_redirect.php [L]        
</IfModule>
# End Muse Generated redirects
```

I don't think relevant but all the resources for that page are in a lower folder at example.com/landing

I want the page at top level, because its a landing page and I don't want it several folders in as google doesn't think things that deep are so important.

I don't care if the solution is something entirely different and not using .htaccess, I just want my html page to run on the domain. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The condition goes above the rule.

Comment: Thanks, rectified whilst waiting for an answer, but still no dice.Now have `# Begin Muse Generated redirects
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/recruitment-advertising\.html$
RewriteRule ^muse_test_redirect.html$ muse_test_redirect.php [L]    
</IfModule>
# End Muse Generated redirects`

Comment: Try it in a different browser, I have literally banged my head against a wall with .htaccess rules only to realize they had somehow cached. Also if you don't mind the site being down a few seconds but some garbage in that file. That will throw a 500 error for everything. If you get the error you know cache isn't your issue. Because honestly if that condition is in the right place it should work.

Comment: nope. just tried firefox, but had been testing in fresh incognito windows on chrome anyway. Is the syntax correct? I tried with and without the forward slash for example. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/recruitment-advertising\.html$`

Comment: It sure looks right to me. Try the error thing, just to be sure it's not a cache issue. And for the record update your question or you're going to get answers telling you the order is wrong.

Comment: thanks, have updated question. I must be barking up the wrong tree then. That's the entire .htaccess file at the moment. And yet I still can't access an html file I added to the server. I don't even know what might be wrong now. google isn't turning up much in search. error thing is just picking up a 404.

Comment: if you type some garbage at the top of your htaccess file the site should throw a 500 error. If it doesn't the site isn't even reading that .htaccess file.

Comment: no 500! well that's odd. I know very little about adobe muse, but being as it added the code to the .htaccess, I assumed it must be using it. how else does it run without it?

Comment: It should be reading it, sounds like you have that caching issue I was talking about, .htacess is processed every time the page is visited, but it is possible your browsers are caching an old one. Try nuking the browser cache. Because if an htaccess file has anything in it that it can't parse it will error out the page. If that isn't happening something is wrong

Comment: nuked, but nothing has changed. still no 500 error, still no page displayed when I try to run my code. It can't be using the .htaccess file.

Comment: I feel stupid now. the ftp access I have been given doesn't start at the root folder. I am in some folder I can't see the name of, down. it had an htaccess file and has hundreds of resource files. I assumed the main site was here as that what I asked for. But I'm in a frickin' repository! Sigh. I'll have to ask on Monday. I need to stop working weekends. I'm too tired and doing stupid stuff.

Comment: haha, well I am 99% sure you have the code right, so there's that. Have a great rest of your weekend!

Comment: cheers rick. you too.